# The request that I send to the Spotify API responds with 404

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

Here is the code of mine. I censored the CLIENT_SECRET and the CLIENT_ID.

```
import requests
import json
import base64

CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID"
CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET"

def get_acces_token(CLIENT_ID: str, CLIENT_SECRET: str) -> str: 
    authURL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

    authHeader = {}

    authData = {
        "grant_type" : "client_credentials"
    }

    # Base 64

    combinated = f"{CLIENT_ID}:{CLIENT_SECRET}"


    message = combinated
    message_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
    base64_combinated = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')



    #         request 

    authHeader['Authorization'] = f"Basic {base64_combinated}"

    res = requests.post(authURL,headers = authHeader,data = authData)

    ACCCES_TOKEN = res.json()['access_token']
    return ACCCES_TOKEN

def get_playlist_tracks(acces_token: str, playlist_id:str) -> dict: 
    playlist_end_point = f"https://accounts.spotify.com/api/playlists/{playlist_id}"

    get_header = {
        "Authorization" : f"Bearer {acces_token}"
    }

    res = requests.get(playlist_end_point,headers=get_header)

    return res


token = get_acces_token(CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET=CLIENT_SECRET)

playlist_id = "3SPj0H71ii0CnhdO6CrhkL?si=c8c41e7c79764265"

tracklist = get_playlist_tracks(token,playlist_id)

print(tracklist)
```

I don't know why does it respond with 404.  The access_token is good. I think that the *playlist_end_point* should be wrong. Do you have any idea what's wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reference](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-playlist-tracks/), the right endpoint is `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks`